# Adding a calculated items in a pivot table in Excel does a cross-product of my fields in rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a data table with fields `Manufacturer`, `Product`, `InOrOut` and `Quantity`.
I turn it into a pivot table. I put `Manufacturer` and `Product` as rows, `InOrOut` as columns and `Quantity` as value.

Everything is fine.

Then I add a calculated field `Total` which formula is `= In - Out`. Then, for reasons I don't understand, my pivot tables show as many rows as there are combinations of `Manufacturer` and `Product`. The added rows have no `In` and no `Out` but a 0 `Total`.

How come?

UPDATE:
Note that I filter the empty rows by values such that `Sum of Quantity` does not equal 0, the useless rows disapear yet my column grand total is not the same for columns `In` and `Out` as they were before filtering.

Comment: What is the distinction between your field `InOrOut` and your inputs to the formula? Where exactly do `In` and `Out` come from?

Comment: `In` and `Out` are the only possible values of `InOrOut`.